# Strange behavior after list lambda expression

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a code fragment that is acting just plain goofy. The following code produces "Debug 1" in the text box.

```
try
{
    tb.Text = "Debug 1";
    TC tcard = lstTimeCards.First(c => c.TimeIn <= dayEnd && c.TimeIn >= dayStart);
    tb.Text = "Debug 2";
}
catch (Exception e)
{}
```

My first and your first answer would likely involve something of the sorts "There is an exception encountered during the lambda search operation." However, this is not the case. During step-debug, tcard is getting assigned to the correct value that I would expect it to get, it simply refuses to do anything with the second *tb.text* operation.

For reference my TC class is as follows:

```
private class TC
{
    public int id;
    public int weekID;
    public int PPID;
    public string UserID;
    public long TimeIn;
    public long? TimeOut;
    public string Comment;
}
```

Does anyone have some insight as to why the second *tb.text* operation is being "ignored"?

Comment: `catch (Exception e) { }` is never good.  At a *minimum*, log something!  As is you're just throwing away valuable error information.  This is a bad habit.

Comment: You aren't doing anything with the second assignment to `tb.Text`.  It isn't clear why you think the code should do anything with it.

Comment: Is this a Windows Forms app? You could add Application.DoEvents(); after the lambda expression and see if it helps.

Comment: @OleEHDufour *DoEvents()* is not  salt to add to every meal.. it should not be needed most of the time, and I can't see why it may be necessay in this case.

Comment: @OleEHDufour nothing is ever made better by adding `Application.DoEvents()` :) edit: except maybe VB6, but only because VB6 lacked any alternatives, so it was the only remaining choice

Comment: There is something dorked up with the dynamic generation of the table and textboxes that are supposed to get assigned a value with this code.

Comment: "it simply refuses to do anything with the second tb.text operation" is very ambiguous. Can you please describe the actual behavior instead of engaging in personification? E.g. "When I step through the line of code, it executes without error, but on the watch pane the `Text` property does not update." Also, please tell us what type `tb` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like it is throwing; a good way to see is:

```
try
{
    ...
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    tb.Text = e.Message;
}
```

The most likely error is that you're asking for `First()`, and there are **not any** matching elements in the date range specified. I realise you say that this doesn't fail when debugging, but: leave the handler in place in your real code and you'll see what is *actually* happening.

Comment: @Jason,  And the less likely error is *lstTimeCards* is null

Comment: After inserting handler, I find that it is getting the value for tb from the ViewState, or some other cache. Disabling viewstate on the control doesn't seem to help. There are some serious issues with textbox value assignment during my page's postback cycle.

Comment: I will accept this answer since it helped me resolve the issue. Being primarily a win-forms dev, I was not handling the event correctly that was utilizing this code. Every time I was debugging, the first time this code was called was on PostBack and I would watch the table controls fill as desired, however upon continuing the debug the code was called again in my event in which, lstTimeCards was not being populated with the items I expected. Thus, falling into my 'catch' statement in which case was overwriting the text box that was previously assigned. Thank you for your positive help!